# How to allow selection of the same item many times in the ListBox

Tags: wpf, xaml

How can I force selection changed anytime there is a click on ListBoxItem?
Here is a sample I created

XAML

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Names}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedName}" />
```

C#

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string selectedName;

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        Names = NamesService.GetNames();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> Names { get; }

    public string SelectedName
    {
        get { return selectedName; }
        set
        {
            selectedName = value;
            //do some work here
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

So when I chose a name from a list, the setter gets hit for SelectedName, but if I click on the same Item for a second time I need it to hit that setter again.

I know I could I chieve it in a different way for example have button inside that and change it to ItemsControl, then bind the button to a command etc.

But I am interested whether I can achieve the above with the ListBox, the way I want it with SelectedItem?

Thanks :)

Comment: Not at all. The SelectedItem won't change when you click another time on the same item.

Comment: What's the point in selecting multiple time the same item? I guess you might want to use an ItemsControl with to handle multiple click.

Comment: You can handle the LeftMouseClick event on the ListBoxItem and thats the only way you can trigger click many times. You can achieve by binding a command to the LeftMouseClick event which can be done using Interativity Trigger. sample https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/06/30/handling-events-in-an-mvvm-wpf-application/

Comment: @Evangelink The point is that this list is a naviagation list, it does nothing more than start a navigation to the selected item. However I have many different ways of navigating around the app, if I then navigate somewhere esle via different method and try to navigate back to a view which happened to be previously selected item, I can't because as far as the ListBox is aware I already have selected this item. Hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: @AyyappanSubramanian Thank you, I'll have a look at it now.

Comment: @adminSoftDK yep totally makes sense! I would strongly recommand to use the ItemsControl for that. People are too often using a ListBox control when it is not required (no need for a selected item) and it is often confusing from an UX point of view.

Answer (score 0):

This did it for me.

Note: In this case you don't need to subscribe to SelectionChanged

```
ListBox_Jumpmarks.AddHandler(Mouse.MouseDownEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(ListBox_Jumpmarks_MouseDown), true);

private void ListBox_Jumpmarks_MouseDown(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   // We only want to do stuff when an item of the ListBox was pressed: Handled = true
   // When the ListBox itself is pressed, we don't want to do stuff: Handled = false
   if (!e.Handled || sender != ListBox_Jumpmarks)
   {
       return;
   }

   // YOUR CODE
   // The selection of the item was done before. So you can now use ListBox.SelectedItem
}
```